# Basic java print

Tags: java

Please note the print statements, in the code segments below. My question is how come If I try to add two doubles in the print statement it prints incorrectly, but if I add them outside the print statement and store the result in a variable than I am able to print it correctly.

Why does this work and print out the correct result?

```
public static void main(String argsp[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double first, second, answer;

        System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
        first = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
        second = input.nextDouble();

        answer = first + second;

        System.out.println("the answer is " + answer);

    }
```

Why does this print out the wrong result?

```
public static void main(String argsp[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double first, second;

        System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
        first = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the second number: ");
        second = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("the answer is " + first+second);

    }
```

Comment: what are the results..??

Comment: works fine for me. Enter the first number: 
2
Enter the first number: 
2
the answer is 2.02.0

Comment: @owengerig OP is trying to make the compiler group operands by proximity. See how those two are cuddling together? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because what you're *basically* doing in that second part is:

```
System.out.println("the answer is " + String.valueOf(first) + String.valueOf(second));
```

That's how the compiler interprets it. Because the `+` operator when you are giving a `String` to a method is not a *calculation* but a *concatenation*.

If you want it done in one line, do it like this:

```
System.out.println("the answer is " + (first + second)); //Note the () around the calculation.
```

Answer (score 3):

In case of doubt with the precedence of operators, just use parens. It is also clearer to read.

```
System.out.println("the answer is " + (first+second));
```

Answer (score 2):

In the second case, the doubles are converted to `String`s because the `+` is considered `String` concatenation.  To work around this, use parentheses to group expressions that should perform numeric calculations:

```
 System.out.println("the answer is " + (first + second));
```